# Are the ratios equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say for some solution S(x,y,z), the conditions are satisfied simultaneously. Then can we conclude that the answer to the question asked in the picture be a YES?

[image]

Comment: Well if $z\not=0$ and $c\not=0$ and $\frac{z}{c(1+b)}=\frac{z}{c(1+a)}$ then doesn't that imply $a=b$?  And similarly $a=c$.  So you'd have to have $a=b=c$ for this to be true.  Also, you're not helping yourself when you use grammar akin to "is the answer be yes?"  People might be more willing to help if you speak like an adult.

Comment: So, does that mean that a=b=c here ?

Comment: No I'm suggesting that *if* $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3$ then $a=b=c$.